# How to write MapReduce code for such scenario?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hive

Say I have a input file as below

```
dept_id emp_id  salary
1       13611   1234
2       13609   3245
3       13612   3251
2       13623   1232
1       13619   6574
3       13421   234
```

Now I want to find the average salary of each department. Like the following Hive query:

```
SELECT dept_id, avg(salary) FROM dept GROUP BY dept_id
```

This will return the output:

```
dept_id avg_sal
----------------
  1     3904.0
  2     2238.5
  3     1742.5
```

Now, what I want to do is to generate the same output, but using the mapreduce framework. So how to write it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try something, post what you tried, and we will help.

Comment: you can start by study the "word count" of map reduce...

Comment: @vefthym I edit question again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **IMPORTANT:**
>   Before attempting to implement this, first try some basic examples in MapReduce, like implementing a word count program, to understand the logic and even before that, read a book or a tutorial about how MapReduce works.

The idea of aggregating stuff (like finding the average) is that you group by key (department id) in the map phase and then you reduce all the salaries of a specific department in the reduce phase.

In a more formalistic way:

**MAP:**

input:a line representing a salary record (i.e., dep_id, emp_id, salary) 
output (key,value): (dep_id, salary)

**REDUCE:**

input (key, values): (dep_id, salaries:list of salary values having this dep_id) 
output (key, value): (dep_id, avg(salaries))

This way, all the salaries that belong to the same department will be handled by the same reducer. All you have to do in the reducer, is find the average of the input values.

Comment: Thank you so much @vefthym, you explain this in very simple way. Now I'll definitely build this code.

Answer (score 2):

code----

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.FloatWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class AverageSalary {
  public static class AvgMapper
       extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, FloatWritable>{
    private Text dept_id = new Text();
    private FloatWritable salary = new FloatWritable(); 
    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
                    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String values[] = value.toString().split("\t");
        dept_id.set(values[0]);
        salary.set(Float.parseFloat(values[2]));
        context.write(dept_id, salary);
    }
  }

  public static class AvgReducer
       extends Reducer<Text,FloatWritable,Text,FloatWritable> {
    private FloatWritable result = new FloatWritable();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<FloatWritable> values,
                       Context context
                       ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      float sum = 0;
      float count = 0;
      for (FloatWritable val : values) {
        sum += val.get();
        count++;
      }
      result.set(sum/count);
      context.write(key, result);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "average salary");
    job.setJarByClass(AverageSalary.class);
    job.setMapperClass(AvgMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(AvgReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(AvgReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(FloatWritable.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("/home/kishore/Data/mapreduce.txt"));  // input path
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("/home/kishore/Data/map3")); // output path
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
  }
}

output 
1   3904.0
2   2238.5
3   1742.5
```

Comment: Krish : Your input path  & output path should be in HDFS? map3 directory should be created or you require new output directory?

Comment: replace this /home/kishore/Data/mapreduce.txt by hdfs;//localhost:9000/filename  same for output

Answer (score 0):

If you have not gone through any training program yet, visit free videos on you tube by edureka for better understanding concepts : [Map Reduce](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SoSlCBjJiUA)

Mapper

Mapper maps input key/value pairs to a set of intermediate key/value pairs.

Maps are the individual tasks that transform input records into intermediate records. The transformed intermediate records do not need to be of the same type as the input records. A given input pair may map to zero or many output pairs.

Reducer

Reducer reduces a set of intermediate values which share a key to a smaller set of values.

The number of reduces for the job is set by the user via Job.setNumReduceTasks(int).

Working example in Apache Hadoop website about :  [Word Count example](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html#Mapper)

For your use case, simple use word count example would not be suffice. 
You have to use Combiner and partitioners on Mapper since you are using Group by. Visit this video : [Advanced Map reduce](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hJaH_vtZlIc&index=6&list=PLNDZVrkihSTsTsLfr0DY5fb9ecaRAWOup)